# django smart_selects - syncdb error

Tags: python, django

getting an error:

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chained_model_field'

while running syncdb after changing my model.

model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat_no = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    cat_txt = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class E_cat(models.Model):
    cat_no = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    cat_txt = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    scat_no = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    scat_txt = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Equip(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        E_cat,
        chained_field="cat_no",
        chained_model_field="cat_no",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
    )
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    mfg_no = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True)
    quanity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True)
    location_zip = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    listings = models.ForeignKey(Listings)
    info = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Problem solved ---  class Equip(models.Model):
                     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
                ===> subcategory = ChainedForeignKey(

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `django.db.models.ForeignKeyField` doesn't accept a `chained_model_field` argument.

You can see this in the traceback you would have received:

```
  File ".../models.py", line 42, in MyModel
    subcategory = m.ForeignKey(…)               <--- here
  File "…/related.py", line 840, in __init__
    Field.__init__(self, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chained_model_field'
```

Possibly you want https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects which defines a `ForeignKey`-like field, which does include a `chained_model_field` argument?